# House prices: Is the rate of increase between years considered difference in difference (DiD)

Tags: difference-in-difference

I am currently doing a study on the impact of transport infrastructure on house prices. There are 2 methods that I would like to explore but I am not sure if the second one is considered difference in difference (DiD).

First Method: 
Treatment group - 800m buffer from station.
Control group - 800m to 1600m buffer from station. Take that difference and compare it between 4 stages of station implementation, i.e. (1)Before, (2)After announcement, (3)During construction and (4)After.

Second Method (looking at the difference in rate of house price increase):
X = Difference of 800m buffer between 4 stages.
Y = Difference of the average house prices between 4 stages.
X-Y = Impact of transport infrastructure.

Q: Would X be considered as treatment and Y be considered as control? Is the second method considered DiD?

OR should I do it this way:
Third Method: Treatment group - 800m buffer from station.
Control group - average house prices for each year. Take that difference and compare it between 4 stages of station implementation.

Each method yields different results and I am confuse as to which method is closest to the DiD method (Second or Third method) and which makes most sense.

Please advice! Thank you!